# Generate a custom unique id and check it does not exist before creating a new user with MySQL and sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a unique id that is 8 characters long for each new user added to a MySQL database. I am using Sequelize along with express to create users. I've created my own custom function: idGen() that simply returns a randomized 8 character string. Using express router I can handle/validate all the form data used to create a new user. The issue I am having is when I generate a new ID I want to check to make sure that ID does not already exist in the database. So far I have this solution:

```js
  Users.findAll().then( data => {
    tableData = data.map(id => id.get('id')); 
    while( tableData.includes(uid) ){
      try {
        uid = idGen(8); 
      } catch( error ){
        return res.status(400).json( error )
      }
    }
  }).then( () => {
    Users.create({
      id: uid,
      name: req.body.name, 
      email: req.body.email
    })
  }).then( user => res.json(user) );
```

This block of code is actually working and saving the new user in the DB, but I am almost certain that this is not the best / right way of doing this. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction and show me a better/proper way to check the random generated ID, and recall idGen(if needed) in a loop before adding a new user?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- instead of find all and then filter in Javascript, why don't you select from the database right away?
- an alternative way I could think of is using a filter like bloom or cuckoo.the false positive rate should be low.
- load ids to redis, probably with redis bloom (https://github.com/RedisBloom/RedisBloom)
- check the new generated id with bloom filter.
- if exists => re-generate id. if not, insert. there could be false positive but the rate is low and you can handle it just the same.

pros:
- no need to check again database every time.
- checking with bloom filter is probably much faster than db.
- scaling redis is easier than db.

cons:
- need redis and redis bloom.